# Deploy Jenkins on micro8s cluster on raspberry pi

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, microk8s

I have a local setup of three raspberry pi's and followed the tutorial on [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-kubernetes-cluster-on-raspberry-pi#1-overview).
I managed to get my microk8s cluster running. Next I wanted to deploy [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/#install-jenkins-with-yaml-files).

Whenever I execute the first command:

```
kubectl create -f jenkins-deployment.yaml -n jenkins
```

I get the following error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

Some other searches suggest installing docker. However in the [tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-kubernetes-cluster-on-raspberry-pi#1-overview) there is nothing about  installing docker. Any ideas what is happening here?

Comment: One of the images probably doesn't exist for arm.

Comment: Some people suggest this can be caused by running an x86 image on ARM. https://github.com/perara/wg-manager/issues/69 Perhaps you could compile the image yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Docker vs. containerd**

Regarding your suggestion about the docker.
[From Version 1.14.0 of MicroK8s (released 25 March 2019) containerd replaced dockerd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55478145/9929015).
Starting from version 1.14.0 containerd automatically ships with MicroK8S installation So, you don't need dockerd as CRI.
Below you can find modules MicroK8S set up during installation:
The [following systemd services](https://tharangarajapaksha.medium.com/start-k8s-with-microk8s-85b67738b557) will be running in your system:

- snap.microk8s.daemon-apiserver, is the kube-apiserver daemon started using the arguments in  `${SNAP_DATA}/args/kube-apiserver`
- snap.microk8s.daemon-controller-manager, is the  kube-controller-manager daemon started using the arguments in  `${SNAP_DATA}/args/kube-controller-manager`
- snap.microk8s.daemon-scheduler, is the kube-scheduler daemon started using the arguments in  `${SNAP_DATA}/args/kube-scheduler`
- snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet, is the kubelet daemon started using the arguments in  `${SNAP_DATA}/args/kubelet`
- snap.microk8s.daemon-proxy, is the kube-proxy daemon started using the arguments in  `${SNAP_DATA}/args/kube-proxy`
- **snap.microk8s.daemon-containerd**, is the containerd daemon started using the configuration in  `${SNAP_DATA}/args/containerd`  and  `${SNAP_DATA}/args/containerd-template.toml`.
- snap.microk8s.daemon-etcd, is the etcd daemon started using the arguments in  `${SNAP_DATA}/args/etcd`

---

**ARM architecture**

Next, Raspberry Pi and, as mentioned previously by community, ARM.
You can not use regular amd64-based images for ARM architecture.

**Possible solutions**

To solve a problem, I recommend you 2 options below.

1. **Use already prepared ARM-based image** of [Jenkins for ARM architecture](https://hub.docker.com/r/mlucken/jenkins-arm).  Also you can search images for Raspberry Pi with filters. Just select which architecture you would like to use: ARM, ARM64, etc.

Some images have been ported for other architectures, and many of these are officially supported (to various degrees).

ARMv6 32-bit (`arm32v6`):  https://hub.docker.com/u/arm32v6/

ARMv7 32-bit (`arm32v7`):  https://hub.docker.com/u/arm32v7/

ARMv8 64-bit (`arm64v8`):  https://hub.docker.com/u/arm64v8/

2. **Prepare your own image for ARM using [buildx](https://github.com/docker/buildx)**

References:

- [Multi-arch build and images, the simple way](https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-build-and-images-the-simple-way/)
- [Cross building ARM images on Docker Desktop](https://carlosedp.medium.com/cross-building-arm64-images-on-docker-desktop-254d1e0bc1f9)